# WMS/WFS Search panel using geoext 2

Tags: extjs, geoext

How to create search panel using geoext 2 which would be fetch data from wms/wfs layer table. Can any one please suggest any example or code to do that.

Comment: Add more info about your question.

Comment: Here the link is available for (GeoExt.form.action.Search) http://geoext.github.io/geoext2/docs/#!/api/GeoExt.form.action.Search and I want to use this code for my own wfs layer but didn't find any example. I am new to programming, so if there is any example availble to describe this in more detaiils in a simple way.

Comment: Yes, I found the solution to this problem using "heron" application and here is the link of example which I used for my application : http://lib.heron-mc.org/heron/1.0.5/examples/formsearchcenter/index.html